# I can't pass arguments to the calling function

Tags: javascript

I am failing to pass arguments to the calling function.

Specifically, I have a table where when I click on the title I have to open a form where the value of the arguments passed must be copied into the various fields of it. To do this, I call through href (as you can see from the code) the function with the parameters passed.

I get the following error:

*Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list*

```js
Object.entries(results).forEach(item => {
  item = item[1];
  let child = document.createElement("tr");
  child.innerHTML = `
                        <td>${item.number}</td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:showFrag(${item.id},${item.number},${item.type});">${item.type}</a></td>`;
  document.querySelector('#my-table').appendChild(child);
})

function showFrag(id, number, type) {
  return id, number, type;
}

function onLoad() {
  showFrag(id, number, type);
  var id = document.getElementById('id');
  var number = document.getElementById('number');
  var type = document.getElementById('type');
  id.value = id;
  numbr.value = number;
  type.value = type;
}
onLoad();
```

```html
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">

    <table id="my-table" width="90%">
      <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Type</th>

      </tr>

    </table>

    <br><br>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered"> <br>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="post" id="save" action="javascript:myFunction()" onload="onLoad()">

        <div class="field">
          <label for="id">ID :</label>
          <input type="number" id="id" name="id" />
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <label for="number">Number:</label>
          <input type="number" id="number" name="number" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="type">Type:</label>
          <select name="type" id="type" form="typeform">
            <option value="Title">Title</option>
            <option value="Text">Text</option>
            <option value="Video">Video</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
          <button type="submit" class="full">Save modifiche</button>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

myFunction() is not present because it has yet to be done, I am only interested in p*assing for now the value of the parameters passed in the various fields of the form* .

result is:

```js
{6: {…}, 8: {…}, 11: {…}, 20: {…}, 21: {…}}
6: {type: 'Text', number: 4, id: 14}
8: {type: 'Text', number: 2, id: 12}
11: {type: 'Image', number: 3, id: 13}
20: {type: 'Video youtube', number: 5, id: 15}
21: {type: 'Title', number: 1, id: 11}
```

Comment: Is `item.type` a string? It needs to be put in quotes.

Comment: Yes. what should i do then?

Comment: @s_o_p_h_i_a You can write `\"`to put a quation sign within quation signs.

Comment: Put quotes around it: `showFrag(${item.id},${item.number},'${item.type}');"`

Comment: @Reporter There's no escaping inside HTML attributes. You have to use the other quotes.

Comment: @Barmar i get this error now right now. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Sounds like you didn't use the proper quotes, maybe you used backticks instead of single quotes.

Comment: @Barmar i put single quotes, but i don't solve anything. Could you please write the entire line?

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around `${item.type}` in the function call if it's a string.

The code to display the values in a the form should be in `showFrag()`, not `onload()`.

```js
Object.entries(results).forEach(item => {
  item = item[1];
  let child = document.createElement("tr");
  child.innerHTML = `
                        <td>${item.number}</td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:showFrag(${item.id},${item.number},'${item.type}');">${item.type}</a></td>`;
  document.querySelector('#my-table').appendChild(child);
})

function showFrag(id, number, type) {
  document.getElementById('id').value = id;
  document.getElementById('number').value = number;
  document.getElementById('type').value = type;
}

function onLoad() {
  # nothing to do for now
}
onLoad();
```

```html
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">

    <table id="my-table" width="90%">
      <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Type</th>

      </tr>

    </table>

    <br><br>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered"> <br>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="post" id="save" action="javascript:myFunction()" onload="onLoad()">

        <div class="field">
          <label for="id">ID :</label>
          <input type="number" id="id" name="id" />
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <label for="number">Number:</label>
          <input type="number" id="number" name="number" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="type">Type:</label>
          <select name="type" id="type" form="typeform">
            <option value="Title">Title</option>
            <option value="Text">Text</option>
            <option value="Video">Video</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
          <button type="submit" class="full">Save modifiche</button>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had done well, unfortunately nothing. I always get that error.

Comment: When do you get the error, when you run the code or when you click on the link?

Comment: When you click on the link.  One thing I am noticing, in the onload function, id is undefined. Maybe it is wrong how I pass the parameters?

Comment: You're calling `showFrag(id, number, type);` before you assign the variables. Move it to after the variable declarations.

Comment: What's the point of calling `showFrag()`? It doesn't show anything, it just returns its arguments. Also, you can't return multiple values like that in JavaScript. You could put them into an array with `return [id, number, type];`

Comment: Doesn't it go first? Because I get the values of the various parameters from the showFrag function

Comment: How is the `Object.entries(results).forEach(...)` related to any of that? Where does `results` come from?

Comment: You get the values with `var id = document.getElementById('id');`

Comment: `id.valiue = id` makes no sense. After that assignment, `id` is a DOM element, not a string that you can put into the value.

Comment: You're not assigning the result of `showFrag()` to anything. The return values are ignored.

Comment: I think you need to review how function calling and returning works, you're confused about the basics.

Comment: Since this is my first time doing such a thing, I'm a beginner, can you modify your code for clarity?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're actually trying to do. Where does the information you're trying to display come from in the first place? What is `results`? Are you making an AJAX call to get the data?

Comment: I just want the id, number and type values to be copied into the form. These values are present in result.

Comment: ID, number, and type of WHAT?

Comment: I changed the answer. See the update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241875/discussion-between-barmar-and-s-o-p-h-i-a).